# Prove the convergence of integration

Tags: integration

$$\int^{+ \infty}_{e} \frac{1}{x \ln^{p} x} dx$$

I want to prove this integral is convergent. The interval of p is not designated.

Comment: Can you provide more context, as in what kind of proof you are attempting? The substitution $x = e^t$ makes the integral $\int_1^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{t^p}dt$, if that's useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u = lnx$, then $x = e \to u = 1$. So $I = \displaystyle \int_{1}^\infty u^{-p} du = \dfrac{u^{-p+1}}{-p+1}|_{u=1}^\infty = +\infty$ if $p \leq 1$ and equal to $\dfrac{1}{p-1}$ if $p > 1$. So it converges if $p > 1$ and diverges otherwise.